# JSF - RichFaces - IE9 re render failure

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am running a web application using RichFaces 4.1.0, mojarra 2.0.2 and apache tomcat 6.0.32.
My app runs well in all the different browsers except IE9.
It stops working in IE 9 and does not generate any javascript error or tomcat logs.
It fails whenever an a4j re-render operation happens. 
I cannot use due to design constraints the meta tag to set the IE9 in compatiblity mode.

Below is my code and web.xml:

```
<h:body>
<h:form>
    <rich:tabPanel switchType="client">
        <rich:tab header="Overview"> 
            <span>Total Number of Applications</span>
        </rich:tab>
        <rich:tab header="Options" onheaderclick="refreshOptions();" >
            <h:outputText value="Logging Level:" />
            <rich:select id="optionsLogLevel" 
                         value="#{optionsBean.logLevel}" 
                         required="true" 
                         requiredMessage="Logging Level is required">
                <f:selectItems value="#{optionsBean.logLevelsList}" />
            </rich:select>
        </rich:tab>
    </rich:tabPanel>
    <a4j:jsFunction name="refreshOptions"
                action="#{optionsBean.refreshOptions}"
                render="optionsLogLevel" execute="@this" />
</h:form>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableEarlyMissingResourceLibraryDetection</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.mitel.bpi.webadmin.model.BPIWebAdminContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: What are the design constraints? I would suggest looking into polyfills which can help older IE (or IE9 in compat mode) still display modern CSS correctly.

Comment: There are a couple of issues in Mojarra with ajax and IE9. Can your try current Mojarra Version 2.1.7?

Answer (score 2):

You are likely hitting [JAVASERVERFACES-2063](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2063), which breaks ajax communications in IE9 due to mis-implemented browser detection in jsf.js.

Upgrading to Mojarra >= 2.1.7 will likely fix your problems.  Upgrade RichFaces while you are at it, 4.1.0.Final is quite long in the tooth now.